# Steam controller stops working (Arch Linux)

Tags: arch-linux, steam, controller

When I plug my controller it works fine. When I start steam, it stops responding. If I plug it out and in again, it works for a while, then stops. The console says:

```
controller.cpp (3640) : Assertion Failed: CGetControllerInfoWorkItem::RunFunc: too many read failures.
Assert( Assertion Failed: CGetControllerInfoWorkItem::RunFunc: too many read failures. ):controller.cpp:3640

Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1476379980)
assert_20161128234100_20.dmp[9557]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20161128234100_20.dmp
Controller uses V1 HID protocol
Steam Controller reserving XInput slot 3
Controller uses V1 HID protocol
controllerabstraction.cpp (82) : Assertion Failed: Error clearing controller mappings.
Controller uses V1 HID protocol
Warning, couldn't get controller details for 0
valvecontrollermanager.cpp (1042) : Assertion Failed: Warning, couldn't get controller details for 0

Controller 3 connected, configuring it now...
Controller 4 connected, configuring it now...
Controller 5 connected, configuring it now...
Controller device closed after hid_read failure
Controller device closed after hid_read failure
Opening joystick Steam Controller
Controller 0 disconnected
Warning, couldn't get controller details for 1
valvecontrollermanager.cpp (1042) : Assertion Failed: Warning, couldn't get controller details for 1

Controller 1 disconnected
Warning, couldn't get controller details for 2
valvecontrollermanager.cpp (1042) : Assertion Failed: Warning, couldn't get controller details for 2

Controller 2 disconnected
assert_20161128234100_20.dmp[9557]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20161128234100_20.dmp[9557]: response: CrashID=bp-fe1900c1-82ba-4853-99e6-c9b922161128
assert_20161128234100_20.dmp[9557]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20161128234100_20.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-fe1900c1-82ba-4853-99e6-c9b922161128''
controllerabstraction.cpp (560) : Assertion Failed: hid_get_feature_report returned false
```

For some reason steam thinks I have 3 controllers (when I check Big Picture). I also tried the instructions from [the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gamepad#Steam_Controller_Not_Pairing)

It was working fine some time ago...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! https://steamcommunity.com/groups/SteamClientBeta/discussions/0/350543951938736491/
The problem is faulty steam, not faulty linux. Just activate steam beta and this fixes the issue.